# Is it possible to convert a const unique_ptr reference (derived class) to a shared_ptr (base class)

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Projectile>> const& projectiles = m_projectileManager->GetProjectiles();
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Enemy>>> const& enemies = m_enemyManager->GetEnemies();

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<EntityBoundingBox>> boundingBoxes;
for (std::unique_ptr<Projectile>const& projectile : projectiles) {
    std::shared_ptr<Entity> entity = std::move(projectile); //error

    std::unique_ptr<EntityBoundingBox> boundingBox = std::make_unique<EntityBoundingBox>(projectile->GetBoundingBox(), entity);
    boundingBoxes.push_back(std::move(boundingBox));
}
```

I'm trying to create a new object, `EntityBoundingBox` but I need to keep a reference to the original `Entity` to determine what has collided with what, but as I am using unique_ptr for the entities, I can't seem to pass them to the new class. Also I am trying to store the type `Entity` which is the base class of `Projectile`

Is there a way to do this without changing from unique_ptr to shared_ptr for storing the `Projectile` and `Enemy` objects and removing the const qualifier?

Constructor for `EntityBoundingBox`

```
EntityBoundingBox(std::shared_ptr<BoundingBox> boundingBox, std::shared_ptr<Entity> entity)
```

Comment: No because a reference to const-qualified `std::unique_ptr` can not release ownership of pointer.

Comment: Well, if something else also stores an owning pointer to a projectile, then the `unique_ptr` is no longer the unique owner...

Comment: Looking at it another way, you can't share ownership of a unique object. It isn't the derived/base pointer part that's problematic

Comment: You *can* create a `shared_ptr` from a `unique_ptr` *if* you `std::move` the `unique_ptr` into the `shared_ptr`. But as @VTT mentions, that's not allowed if your `unique_ptr` is `const` and there's no way of doing this while preserving the original `unique_ptr` (it isn't a unique owner anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and here's why: If you have only a `unique_ptr<>const&`, you have no right to extend the life of the referenced object. When the underlying `unique_ptr` you have a reference to goes away, so does the object. But if you have a `shared_ptr<>`, you do have the right to extend the life of the referenced object. So with only what you have, you cannot give what is required.

It may help to think about why you would ever pass a `shared_ptr` to some piece of code. Unless that code might need to extend the life of the referenced object, it makes more sense just to pass a reference. If you are passing a `shared_ptr`, it would be because that code may copy that `shared_ptr` and expect it to extend the object's life. That can't work if something else is going to destroy the object regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case I wasn't sure on exactly what to do. I was looking to pass the `Entity` into the `EntityBoundingBox` constructor and store it temporarily, but I've read that it's bad to store references as class members. So I thought that using a `shared_ptr` might have been the only way.

Comment: It really comes down to how the lifetime of the `Entity` is going to be managed. If you want it to persist until neither code path needs it, then construct it with `make_shared` from the beginning and stash `shared_ptr`s to it. Code should not take a `shared_ptr` unless it wants/needs to extent the life of the object.

Comment: I guess I should say that you actually can do this. You construct a `shared_ptr` with an empty deleter. If any code attempts to extend the object's life through the `shared_ptr` it will fail, but so long as you are 100% sure this isn't needed, it will work fine. It will just be very hard to understand and maintain and is definitely something you should avoid. This is far worse than stashing a reference in a class though.

Comment: Yeah I don't think I'll go down that path. I think I've achieved what I want using a `weak_ptr`. Whether it is a correct use case I'm not sure, but it seems to be what I'm looking for.